# How many levels do I need to level a pet for it to count as "levelling it myself"?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

All over WoW you can battle various wild pets and you can potentially capture them. They have all different levels depending on where you're battling them (higher level zones tend to have higher level pets).

For the Tournament of Celestials, you need to have 15 pets levelled to 25, that you "levelled yourself".

What counts as levelling them myself? Taking them from 1-25? Or can I encounter a level, say, 23 pet in the wild, level it 2 more levels, and that's countable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order for a pet to count as being "leveled yourself", you have to level it up at least one time.  You can buy level 24 pets, level them up once, and this will count towards the 15 pet requirement.

This is confirmed in wowhead comments for the [Pro Pet Group](https://www.wowhead.com/achievement=6578/pro-pet-group) achievement.

Comment: Does using lvl 25 petboosts count towards leveling it yourself?

Comment: Yes. I have used a level 25 pet boost and it counted towards the achievement.